# How to add CSS autocomplete to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, autocomplete

i am using eclipse **helios 3.6**
and i am developing **JSF pages** (Dynamic Web Project With JSF Capabilities)
and sometimes i need to add style to a component in the xhtml page

```
<h:commandLink style="margin-righ:10px">
```

(not a style class)
and i want to add CSS autocomplete to eclipse
how to do so ? please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go:

Window -> Preferences -> Web -> CSS files -> Editor -> Content assist.

And make sure the checkboxes are checked

**EDIT:** Ok... Then try with these:

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Content Types -> Text -> JSP -> Add (*.css)

**OR**

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Content Types -> Text -> Java Source File -> Add (*.css)

Try with these and see if it solves your problem

**EDIT 2:** Plus try this:

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Association -> Add (*.css)

**EDIT 3:**

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Association

make sure it looks like this, it works for me with the autocompletion:

[image]

Comment: in fact they are checked, maybe that works in css files only ?

Comment: you noticed that i asked for autocomplete in xhtml page not in css file ?

Comment: doesn't work either no css proposal, no css template proposal, no default proposal.

Comment: Sorry I've been away. Ok, so it's a .JSP file containing xHTML right?
Look at my edit.

Comment: no it's a .xhtml file that contains JSF, and i tried to open it with JSP editor and also the web page editor, and nothing works, still there's no css autocomplete, maybe i am missing something in my project configuration ?

Comment: Ok so you've opened it with IDE's other than Eclipse and the autocompletion doesn't work there either..? If so this sounds very strange to me.

Comment: after applying all above steps and restarting eclipse, i am getting this exception: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914131/could-not-open-the-editor-null-charset-name please advise

Comment: hmm... there seems to be something really wrong with your environment configuration... this looks like an old bug that could appear in the IDE, that has been fixed, I can't see why you're getting it... I don't know honestly, re-install Eclipse? If that's not too great of an issue..?

Comment: Allright mate, I wish you the best of luck. Those guys roaming the Eclipse forum should be able to tell you what's wrong I'm sure!

Comment: BTW, what eclipse version do you use ?

Comment: Version: 3.6.2.r362_v20110210-9gF78Gs1FrIGnHDHWkEcopoN8AmxeZflGDGKQi
Build id: M20110210-1200

Comment: So it should be pretty much the same version as you're using

Comment: What tripped me, was that I had to press ctrl-space to get the suggestion box, while in the php-editor it would pop up automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a WTP extension plugin ([WTP Web resources](https://github.com/angelozerr/eclipse-wtp-webresources/wiki/Installation-Update-Site)).  See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43549935/2459094.