# Could not open the editor: Null charset name

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jakarta-ee

i am using eclipse **helios 3.6**
when i tried to open xhtml pages with web page editor 
i got the following error:

```
Could not open the editor: Null charset name
```

yesterday it was working fine, but today it keeps giving me above error for all xhtml pages.

any ideas how to solve it ?

**UPDATE**: Full StackTrace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null charset name
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup(Charset.java:429)
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.isSupported(Charset.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.encoding.CodedIO.createEncodingMemento(CodedIO.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.encoding.CodedIO.createMemento(CodedIO.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.encoding.CodedReaderCreator.checkForEncodingInContents(CodedReaderCreator.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.encoding.CodedReaderCreator.findMementoFromStreamCase(CodedReaderCreator.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.encoding.CodedReaderCreator.getEncodingMemento(CodedReaderCreator.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.document.AbstractDocumentLoader.createNewStructuredDocument(AbstractDocumentLoader.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.document.AbstractDocumentLoader.createNewStructuredDocument(AbstractDocumentLoader.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.AbstractModelLoader.load(AbstractModelLoader.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl._doCommonCreateModel(ModelManagerImpl.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl._commonCreateModel(ModelManagerImpl.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl.getModelForEdit(ModelManagerImpl.java:1405)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.css2.CSSUtil.getUserAgentDefaultStyleSheet(CSSUtil.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.css2.CSSUtil.getDefaultCSSDeclaration(CSSUtil.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.css2.style.AbstractStyle.calculateDefaultDeclaration(AbstractStyle.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.css2.style.AbstractStyle.getDefaultDeclaration(AbstractStyle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.css2.style.AbstractStyle.calculateProperty(AbstractStyle.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.css2.style.AbstractStyle.getStyleProperty(AbstractStyle.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.css2.style.AbstractStyle.getDisplay(AbstractStyle.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.css2.layout.CSSFigure.regetLayout(CSSFigure.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.css2.layout.CSSFigure.invalidateCSS(CSSFigure.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.css2.layout.CSSFigure.setCSSStyle(CSSFigure.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.figurehandler.DefaultFigureHandler.updateFigure(DefaultFigureHandler.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.figurehandler.FigureFactory.updateDeepFigure(FigureFactory.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.parts.ElementEditPart.refresh(ElementEditPart.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.parts.ElementEditPart.refresh(ElementEditPart.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(AbstractEditPart.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.parts.NodeEditPart.addNotify(NodeEditPart.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.parts.ElementEditPart.addNotify(ElementEditPart.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(AbstractEditPart.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refreshChildren(AbstractEditPart.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.parts.DocumentEditPart.refreshChildren(DocumentEditPart.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.parts.DocumentEditPart.refreshChildren(DocumentEditPart.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(AbstractEditPart.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.parts.DocumentEditPart.refresh(DocumentEditPart.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(AbstractEditPart.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.parts.NodeEditPart.addNotify(NodeEditPart.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(AbstractEditPart.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.SimpleRootEditPart.setContents(SimpleRootEditPart.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.AbstractEditPartViewer.setContents(AbstractEditPartViewer.java:617)
    at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.AbstractEditPartViewer.setContents(AbstractEditPartViewer.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.SimpleGraphicalEditor.setModel(SimpleGraphicalEditor.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.HTMLEditor.connectDesignPage(HTMLEditor.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.HTMLEditor.createPages(HTMLEditor.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2863)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2768)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2760)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2711)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2707)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2691)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu.openEditor(OpenWithMenu.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu$2.handleEvent(OpenWithMenu.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have not  specified the coding(e.g. u`tf-8,gbk` and so on) or hava specified  a wrong one(didn't match yo).