# CSS proposals without pressing ctrl+space

Tags: css, eclipse

Right now if I am in a css file and start typing something and press `ctrl + space` I get autocomplete suggestions, but is it possible to get that just by typing, without actually pressing `ctrl + space` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900575/how-to-add-css-autocomplete-to-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You can try to mess with the settings by going to `Settings -> Preferences -> Auto-Completion`

Also make sure that you have language set to css or just the file saved as a css.