# JavaFX CSS Files don't autocomplete in Eclipse

Tags: java, css, eclipse, javafx

I am making a JavaFX Application and want to use stylesheets. I don't work directly with the Scene Builder tool (although I set it up: downloaded Scene Builder and added Eclipse plugin "e(fx)clipse").

In Eclipse I just started a normal Project (**File > New > Java Project**).
I created a file "style.css" by **right clicking on a package > New > File**.

As an example for my style.css file:

```
.root {
    -fx-font: 16px "Serif";
    -fx-padding: 10;
    -fx-background-color: #CCFF99;
}
```

When I edit this file I want to have the eclipse autocomplete and "suggestion" feature enabled. But when I press "Ctrl + Space" it doesn't show any suggestions. How to fix this?

## Edit:

As suggested in the 'possible duplicate link' [How to add CSS autocomplete to eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900575/how-to-add-css-autocomplete-to-eclipse). I tried the following (without any success):

Went to **Window -> Preferences -> General -> Content Types -> Text -> Java Source File -> Add (*.css)** (added *.css, but autocomplete still fails)

Went to **Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Association -> Add (*.css)*** (.css was already in here ...)

The other are JSP related and I have no Idea what they are talking about. Any suggestions to solving this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add CSS autocomplete to eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900575/how-to-add-css-autocomplete-to-eclipse)

Comment: Right click on the file and check the Open With menu. Are you opening this file with the e(fx)clipse CSS editor?

Comment: Yes the file gets opened with the e(fx)clipse CSS editor. It seems like it needs to be configured in some way.

Answer (score 1):

The project needs to have the JavaFX Classpath container!

- Open the properties of the project
- Go to Java Build Path
- Select Libraries Tab
- Click Add Library
- Select JavaFX SDK